# How to merge time intervals where appropriate?

Tags: c, algorithm, intervals

I'm making a shared expenses management software to calculate debt between people renting a room within the same house. This software is available at https://github.com/quirinpa/sem. When someone pays a bill, it finds out who is present and during which intervals of time within the billing period, from which it then calculates the cost for that person, and how much they have to pay to who payed the bill. I use two sets of databases for these intervals, one that includes temporary leaves, and another that doesn't. I want to make sure that, when everybody has left temporarily, the price for that amount of time is shared between all of them. Basically it boils down to the following problem:

Example 1:

```
      l
o------------o - - - - - - - - - - - - -o
      el                         el
o------------o - - - - - - o------------o
      q                          q
o------------o - - - - - - o------------o

o------------o-------------o------------o
x            w             z            y

L1 = [(x, w, { l, el, q }), (z, y, { el, q })]
L2 = [(x, y, { l, el, q })]
Target = [(x, z, { l, el, q }), (z, y, { el, q })]
```

Example 2:

```
      l
o------------o
      el                         el
o------------o - - - - - - o------------o
      q                          q
o------------o - - - - - - o------------o

o------------o-------------o------------o
x            w             z            y

L1 = [(x, w, { l, el, q }), (z, y, { el, q })]
L2 = [(x, w, { l, el, q }), (w, y, { el, q })]
Target = [(x, w, { l, el, q }), (w, y, { el, q })]
```

L1 is the list accounting for temporary leaves.
L2 is the list that doesn't care about that, just when they started and stopped renting a room.
Target is what I want to obtain.
The elements of each is (min, max, list_of_participants).
The solid lines are periods where the person in question is present. The dashed lines are periods where they are temporarily absent. The absence of a line indicates the person is not renting a room at that time.

Can you please help me find the algorithm?
[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363091/split-overlapping-ranges-into-all-unique-ranges/363096#363096) is related in the sense that it was used in the code, to find L1 and L2.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You need to make an attempt at solving the problem.  Otherwise this question is likely to be closed by a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by querying the empty intervals on the databases that do not account for pauses. This produces a few extra results, but it is fine. See [here](https://github.com/quirinpa/sem/blob/dfbb92d1c7dc35ef9c05a53a85a339a5cc83109c/sem.c#L762) for details.